# What does "j'ai loupé" mean and how is it used?

Tags: vocabulaire, registre-familier

I saw the expression "J'ai loupé" which apparently meant, "I missed..." But I can't find it in a dictionary. Is this expression correct? If so what is the infinitive of loupe?

How is it different from the words "manquer" and "rater"? What is the best way to say something like, "I missed the meeting."?

Comment: It can easily be found in [dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/louper). It is colloquial. In formal speech you'd better use *manquer*. *Rater* is also  rather informal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forme la plus correcte, à l'écrit comme à l'oral:

> J'ai manqué la réunion.

Forme un peu moins soutenue (mais correcte). On *rate* plutôt un *examen* (*échouer à*), très souvent utilisée à l'oral:

> J'ai raté la réunion.

Forme familière, à réserver à l'oral:

> J'ai [loupé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/louper) la réunion.

Comme pour beaucoup de néologismes, *louper* se conjugue comme un verbe du premier groupe (*aimer*).

Forme plus récente, *moderne*, moins familière, également orale, mais qui peut aussi signifier, *j'ai manqué délibérément*:

> J'ai zappé la réunion.

Zapper se conjugue également comme un verbe du premier groupe.

Forme équivalente, plus ancienne (manquer délibérément), traditionnellement et très fréquemment employée dans le domaine scolaire:

> J'ai séché la réunion. J'ai séché les cours.

La forme *sécher un examen* a aussi l'autre sens de *rater* (faillir à) *l'examen*, d'où est dérivé le mot familier très employé anti-sèche (tout procédé licite ou non pour éviter ce fâcheux événement).

Autre possibilité, plus large, assez familière - qui signifie également *j'ai sabordé, torpillé, saboté*:

> J'ai planté la réunion.

Comment: Je trouve que "zappé" est plus proche de "oublié", non ?

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Pas annuler, « j'ai zappé la réunion » se dit plutôt si on a, volontairement ou non, fait autre chose qu'y assister.

Comment: Pour “manquer **délibérément**,” il y a aussi [sécher](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/s%C3%A9cher+l'%C3%A9cole) =to skip/ditch/blow off (play hooky).

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Seul son organisateur à le pouvoir d'annuler une réunion. Tout autre participant qui *zappe* la réunion ne peut pas l'annuler. Ils fait autre chose. Voici un exemple de personne ayant *zappé* une réunion involontairement: http://www.wam-poker.com/forums/discussion-22-voila-la-team-49059?p=2779180

Comment: ref: _Zapper_ : [trans.](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/zapper_v/10910041?q=zapper#802604), [intrans.](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/zapper/83049?q=zapper#82062) ; [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/zapper). @jlliagre Merci, je n'ai que peu prêté attention au contexte ; je comprends.

Comment: Histoire d'apporter ma pierre noire-jaune-rouge à la conversation, je préciserais qu'en Belgique, on "brosse" les cours, en France on les "sèche" :-)